# cURL JSON + Cookies + Header Params + Jersey

Tags: java, http, cookies, curl, jersey

I'm trying to send a request, I do the following in curl:

```
curl -v --header "location: 60.004:8.456" --cookie "sessionToken=~session" -i -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"data":"{"FCT":"Welcome", "Uni":"Welcome to DI"}"}' localhost:8080/tester/apps/e39/data
```

and for some reason it matches the class but no this method:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createDocumentRoot(JSONObject inputJsonObj,
        @Context UriInfo ui, @Context HttpHeaders hh) {
}
```

Edit:
The class is defined with @Path("{appId}/data")

The problem isn't the paths, as I've debugged it and seen it identifies the class right, it just throws the bad request after going inside the class without entering any method.

Here is the curl verbose:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
> PUT /tester/apps/e39/data HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4                         libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: sessionToken=~session
> location: 60.004:8.456
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 60
> 
* upload completely sent off: 60out of 60 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 990
Content-Length: 990
< Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2013 21:46:56 GMT
Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2013 21:46:56 GMT
< Connection: close
Connection: close
```

Comment: Very hard to tell without seeing the `@Path` annotations on the class and method.  Please could you provide some more code?

Comment: Added the curl verbose and some other info. The problem is not with the Path annotation but in the matching of the http request content with the method.

Comment: Thank you jgm, you were most kind. The problem was in the json that was not written properly, I'll write an answer incase someone gets as confused as I did.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the json syntax that was incorrect, I had

```
'{"data":"{"FCT":"Welcome", "Uni":"Welcome to DI"}"}'
```

after changing to this, it worked fine:

```
'{"data":
{"FCT":"Welcome",
"Uni":"Welcome to DI"}}'
```

I used a JSON online parser to check the json syntax, here is the link incase someone needs it:
http://json.parser.online.fr/